# Is non-invertibility a problem for (AR)MA processes?

Tags: time-series, arima, stochastic-processes, moving-average, box-jenkins

I'm reading *Time Series Analysis: Forecasting and Control (3rd ed.)* by Box, Jenkins and Reinsel.

There are some arguments about **invertibility** that I can't wrap my head around.

Considering a MA(1) model:

[image: img 1]

Here it says: *"the current deviation $z_t$ in (3.1.4) depends on $z_{t-1}$,$z_{t-2}$,...,$z_{t-k}$ with weights that increase as $k$ increases."*
This seems in contrast with [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/414457/318559) which I agree with, it doesn't feel correct to state that $z_t$ depends more and more on past values, since there is actually statistical independence for lags greater that 1. The problem is that in (3.1.4) there are a lot of terms that cancel out (actual math in the cited answer). **(1)** I am missing something, why would the above statement be true?

Moreover:

[image: img 2]

Assuming the process is Gaussian, I get that invertibility assures the model is identifiable, but I don't understand why would it make a difference in how we associate past happenings with present. For almost each invertible Gaussian process there is a non-invertible one that defines the **same distribution**, so I would argue that the two processes associate the past with the present in the **same manner**, **(2)** where am I wrong?

If we don't assume Gaussian distribution, **(3)** then why would we exclude the possibility of a process being non-invertible, effectively excluding some distributions that could be closer (and maybe predict better) the real process underlying the phenomenon being studied?

Again, in chapter 6, about model identification:
[image: img 3]
And
[image: img 4]

Earlier it is stated: “*Identification methods are rough procedures applied to a set of data to indicate the kind of representational model worthy of further investigation. The specific aim here is to obtain some idea of the values of d, p, q ... and to obtain initial estimates for the parameters*”.

So, to assure the identification procedure can logically be used to *uniquely* identify a model (why couldn’t more than one model be “identified” for further investigation?), they exclude non invertibile models, apparently making them “*not worthy of further investigation*”. To me this makes sense only if we assume normality. They seem to point that “expressing the current value $w_t$ exclusively in terms of previous history” is required for a model, **(4)** why would it be?

Comment: @RichardHardy I am not sure either, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: No, I do not, as I indicated above :) Nevermind.